# Simple email validation script

Tags: python, python-2.x, validation, email

I was doing a programming challenge and the object was to validate an email address, I wrote a simple little email validator and would like some input on how I can make it more efficient.

How it works, it has two validations, one with a regex, and one validating the length (most email addresses are over 12 characters, so that's what I went with).
The regex checks for an `@` and a `.` symbol. This is all inside of its own validation class.

Source:

```
import re


class Validator(object):

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email

    def check_for_symbol(self):
        if re.search("[@.]", self.email) is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def check_length(self):
        if len(self.email) >= 12:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def email_to_verify():
    return raw_input('Enter your email address: ')


def check_email(email):
    validator = Validator(email)
    symbol = validator.check_for_symbol()
    if symbol is False:
        print "Your email address is not valid. Failed symbols.."

    length = validator.check_length()
    if length is False:
        print "Your email is not valid. Failed length"

    if length and symbol is True:
        print "Email is a valid email address."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = email_to_verify()
    check_email(e)
```

Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Examples of usage:

```
C:\challenges>python email_val.py
Enter your email address: test
Your email is not valid. Failed symbols check.
Your email is not valid. Failed length check.

C:\challenges>python email_val.py
Enter your email address: te@t.t
Your email is not valid. Failed length check.

C:\challenges>python email_val.py
Enter your email address: gmail@gmail.gmail
Email is a valid email address.
```

Comment: I'm really curious to know why you consider an address with less than 12 characters not an email address. It's not because most email address are > 12 characters that email address with < 12 characters are not valid.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Honestly, just through 12 in there because 90% of the people this is made for have their first and last names as their email address.

Comment: The code claims that `aaaaaa.bbbbbb@` is a valid address...

Comment: @vnp That's outstanding lol

Comment: Note that context-dependent email addresses don't necessarily have a fully-qualified DNS name - in many organisations, partial names are resolved (e.g. within `example.com`, an address such as `controller@finance` is exactly equivalent to `controller@finance.example.com`.

Comment: The code claims that `@@@@@@@@@@@@` is a valid email address

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Interface design

The current design of the validator class is not very intuitive.
Users of this class must call the `check_for_symbol` and `check_length` methods to validate an email address.
They would only know this by reading the implementation.
You could add documentation,
but it would still not be easy to use.
The best is when the usage and behavior is obvious.

I would imagine the design of an email validator something like this:

```
class EmailValidator:
    def validate(self, email):
        # ...
```

Where the `validate` method would raise exceptions depending on what failed (such as length, symbols).

With such outline, even without documentation,
when a user does `help(EmailValidator)` and sees a single `validate` method,
the usage is obvious, clear.

What's worse,
the `check_email` function is not part of the validator class.
As such, the validator doesn't encapsulate the validation logic.
That might be acceptable if the public API is the `check_email` and the class is the implementation detail.

#### Coding style

Use boolean expressions directly. For example, instead of this:

> ```
> def check_for_symbol(self):
>     if re.search("[@.]", self.email) is None:
>         return False
>     else:
>         return True
> ```

You could write as:

```
def check_for_symbol(self):
    return re.search("[@.]", self.email) is not None
```

Also, instead of `x is True`, use simply `x`, and instead of `x is False`, use `not x`.

See more on this in the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

#### Compatibility with Python 3

When using Python 2,
to future-proof yourself it's good to adopt a writing style compatible with Python 3. For example, instead of `print 'something'`, write `print('something')`.

Comment: Would you consider the boolean expressions directly to be more readable? It seems that using that directly could be confusing.

Comment: Yes, naturally more readable. Note also that this is explicitly recommended by the style guide.

Comment: sorry for the easy question, I have no idea what I'm doing in case you couldn't tell lol. Thank you!